# Bind TestService dependency LifeCycle to a Xunit test with a Test Server in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, xunit.net, testserver

I use c# test Server to do some of my test but i have to start a New test Server for each Xunit Fact. This is due to the fact that i have some Fake implémentation that Fake persistance and even with data fuzzing sometimes their is conflict if thé Server IS shared. Moreover the test suite grows and it starts to take Time.
So I Wonder someone have succeed to use test Server and bind TestService dependency to Xunit Fact LifeCycle ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by managing the lifetime of your dependencies within the xUnit test lifecycle. xUnit provides several fixtures and lifecycle hooks that you can use to control the setup and teardown of resources, including test servers and their dependencies.

One common approach is to use a test fixture to manage the lifecycle of shared resources such as test servers. You can then configure your test server within the fixture's setup method (**ctor** in xUnit) and dispose of it in the teardown method (**Dispose()** in xUnit). Additionally, you can use constructor injection to inject the test server or other dependencies into your test classes.

**For example, this is how you can structure your tests using xUnit fixtures:**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Xunit;

//TestServerFixture is a fixture class responsible for setting up and tearing down the test server.
//The TestServerFixture sets up the test server in its constructor and disposes of it when Dispose() is called.
public class TestServerFixture : IDisposable
{
    public TestServer Server { get; private set; }

    public TestServerFixture()
    {
        // Configure and start the test server
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>();
        Server = new TestServer(builder);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Dispose of the test server when the fixture is disposed
        Server.Dispose();
    }
}

//MyTestClass is a test class that uses the TestServerFixture as a fixture by implementing IClassFixture.
public class MyTestClass : IClassFixture<TestServerFixture>
{
    private readonly TestServerFixture _fixture;

    public MyTestClass(TestServerFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // Use the test server in your test
        var client = _fixture.Server.CreateClient();
        // Perform test actions
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        // Use the test server in another test
        var client = _fixture.Server.CreateClient();
        // Perform test actions
    }
}
```

- **TestServerFixture** is a fixture class responsible for setting up and tearing down the test server.
- **MyTestClass** is a test class that uses the **TestServerFixture** as a fixture by implementing **IClassFixture**.
- Each test method in **MyTestClass** receives an instance of **TestServerFixture** through constructor injection.
- The **TestServerFixture** sets up the test server in its constructor and disposes of it when **Dispose()** is called.

By using this approach, you can ensure that each test method gets its own instance of the test server, scoped to the lifecycle of the test class. This allows you to isolate your tests and manage dependencies more effectively.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding i want to scope the LifeCycle of some dependency injected into the test Server through test service and bind their LifeCycle to a Xunit Fact

Comment: Thank you for clarifying , So you want to limit the lifecycle of dependencies injected into the test server and bind their lifecycle to an xUnit reality? it's true?

Comment: Yes it is exactly this .